# How to read/import the roles from an external IDP into Keycloak

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak, jdbcrealm

I have a spring boot application secured with Keycloak 11.0.2, and my Keycloak setup is as follows:

- A Realm named `Central` with a role `CentralWebUser` and a client `SpringWeb`. The client has

  - `Access Type` : `public` and only one flow enabled, namely `Standard Flow Enabled`
  - `Valid Redirect URIs` : http://localhost:8000/*
- A 2ª realm named `SpringApp` with a role `WebUser` and a client `spring_brokering`

  - A user named `springuser` with the realm role `WebUser`
  - The client `spring_brokering` has only the `Standard Flow Enabled` set to ON, `Valid Redirect URIs` : http://localhost:8080/*, and `Access Type` : `Confidential`

The second realm is an IDP of the first. So to login a user goes to the `Central` login page and selects the IDP `SpringAppIDP`.

The IDP configuration is as follows:

- `alias` : `SpringAppIDP`, with everything else being `OFF` except for the option enabled
- The Authorization URL, Token URL, and so on are set to the URLs from the `SpringApp` endpoints (`e.g.,`  `Authorization URL` : http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/SpringApp/protocol/openid-connect/auth)
- Client ID and Client secret are the `spring_brokering` and its secret, respectively.

On the Spring side, I have the following properties worth mentioning:

```
server.port                         = 8000
keycloak.realm                      = Central
keycloak.auth-server-url            = http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required               = external
keycloak.resource                   = SpringWeb
keycloak.public-client=true

keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=WebUser
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/services/*
```

When I access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/services` I got redirected to the Keycloak `Central` Realm Login page, then I click the `SpringAppIDP` and enter the username `springuser` and its password. The login is successful, but I got an **access denied**, which means that the user `springuser` does not have the role `WebUser`. However, that role was assigned to that user within the second realm (*i.e.,* `SpringApp`).

Interestingly, if in the first Realm I create an identity provider Mapper `External Role to Role` (in the IDP  `SpringAppIDP` configuration) mapping the external role of `WebUser` to the `CentralWebUser` and change the spring properties to :

```
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=CentralWebUser
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/services/*
```

I am able to login, which means that Keycloak knew that the user had the `WebUser` role, hence mapping that role to the `CentralWebUser` role.

I would like to know if it is possible to explicitly import the roles from an external IDP into an internal one? Or if (and how) can I request a token on behalf of the user that would have that users' roles from both the `Central` and  `SpringWeb` Realm in the that token, without having to explicitly create a Role Mapper for each user role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know if it is possible to explicitly import the roles
> from an external IDP into an internal one? Or if (and how) can I
> request a token in behalf to the user that would have that users'
> roles from both the Central and  SpringWeb Realm in the that token,
> without having to explicitly creating a Role Mapper for each user
> role.

Without explicitly creating a Role Mapper for each user role, the only solution that I have found was to extend the Keycloak code; which comes with obvious downsides.

In retrospect, it *actually* makes sense that Keycloak does not offer out-of-the-box a way of automatically importing all the roles from the *external* IDP. For instance, if I am using Google as an external IDP why should my internal IDP (*i.e.*, Keycloak) care about the exact name of the roles used by Google?!. Most-likely, either those roles are meaningless for the internal IDP, and when they are meaningful they might have a different name. Regardless, for those exceptions, one can use the Role Mapper feature.

Nevertheless, to automatize a bit the process, I have created a file that maps the roles of the *internal* IDP to *external* IDP, for instance:

```
ROLE A | ROLE B
....
```

I also have a JSON file with a *template* of a Role Mapper example with some tags to be replaced afterwards (*e.g.,* the fields `role` and `external.role`).

With scripts, I read the file that has the mapping between roles, and use [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html) to create the roles, the mappers and so on.

The logic that I have used is as follows:

- If the role does not exist in the *external* IDP I just skipped and assume that it was a mistake;
- If the role does not exist in the *internal* IDP I create it as a Realm Role; For that, I use the endpoint `POST /{realm}/roles`
- Finally, I create the Role Mapper using the endpoint `POST /{realm}/identity-provider/instances/{alias}/mappers` with the content of the `JSON` template Role Mapper file (with its tags replaced, accordingly).

The rationale for not creating the Realm Role in the *external* IDP is that all the roles from the *external* IDP should have been loaded already from the LDAP anyway. For the *internal* IDP, I do create because it is expectable that for mappings 1 to 1 that the roles from the LDAP (loaded into the *external* IDP) are not yet created on the *internal* IDP.